# What is the best way to sort and filter data in a table with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, datatable, filtering, ngtable

How can I sort and filter data in a table with AngularJS?

The rows of my table are interactive. Users can delete/add a row. I've looked into ng-table, it's more complicated than I thought when the data in the table is constantly changing. I've also heard of datatable from Bootstrap but it looks like it doesn't work too well in my use case.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use smart-table has great documentation and easy to use.

http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/

Almost all of the functionalities that you need is there.

Cheers, Priz

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [Angular UI grid](http://ui-grid.info/).

I have personally used this grid and it perform nice with huge data.